# loop through multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

some time small things in programming get giants. I am working on 2 dimensional array but I am unable to get what I need.

below is my array structure.

```
  Array
      (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16
        [id] => 16
        [1] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [2] => abc@gmail.com
        [email] => abc@gmail.com
        [3] => dffsdf
        [message] => dffsdf
        [4] => 0
        [status] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
        [id] => 17
        [1] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [2] => xyz@gmail.comnnn
        [email] => xyz@gmail.comnnn
        [3] => dffsdfnnnnnnnnnnn
        [message] => dffsdfnnnnnnnnnnn
        [4] => 0
        [status] => 0
    )
  )
```

what I am doing here is getting the messages for a user with some id. I am doing it like that

```
  if($get_mails[0]['userid'] == $_GET['userid'])
  {

$last_key = end(array_keys($get_mails));

echo '{"Messages":[';

foreach($get_mails as $key => $get_each_mail){

$company_name = $get_each_mail['company_name'];
$email_id = $get_each_mail['id'];
$email_body = $get_each_mail['message'];
}
echo '{"CompanyName":"'.$company_name.'","MessageID":"'.$email_id.'","MessageBody":"'.$email_body.'"';

if ($key == $last_key) 
{
  echo '}]}';
}else{
     echo'},';
     }
}
```

what I am unable to do is so funny that I need a loop for [0] in this line of code

```
if($get_mails[0]['userid'] == $_GET['userid'])
```

like

```
if($get_mails[i]['userid'] == $_GET['userid']) and it give me all the records against specific user.
```

here is what I want to get for a specific user

```
 {"Messages":[{"CompanyName":"newtech","MessageID":"14","MessageBody":"hi how are you"},{"CompanyName":"newtech","MessageID":"15","MessageBody":"hi how are you"},{"CompanyName":"newtech","MessageID":"24","MessageBody":"asfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd"}]}
```

respose like that, it will add more and more if more records would available against specific user.

Comment: Are you trying to make JSON?

Comment: yes exactely i am making jason

Comment: Use `json_encode()` for that instead of trying to echo the correct characters. Could you add the structure of the desired json to the question?

Comment: [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) will give you the last item in your array, not the item you just matched. Also, don't build JSON manually. Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: i use end() just to get the last row id for the condition in the end

Comment: my code is working fine for me every thng is ok i just need to loop the first parameter up to the value to total number of rows found in db against specific user

Comment: i hard code it for now like [0] but i need it to be dynamic

Comment: So your array is a resultset from the database? I suggest using only associative fetches, so you don't get the numeric keys...

Comment: What is the reason to duplicate the keys in your array? Like 0 and `id` both pointing to 16?

Comment: You really should just `SELECT` only exactly what you need from the database, `json_encode()` the query results, and call it a day. What you have here is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: `$get_mails[i]` won't work in php, you need `$get_mails[$i]`

Comment: Please don't edit "SOLVED" in question titles. That's what the checkmark is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$get_mails` contains the Array you posted above (including `company_name`), you can write something like this:

```
$output = Array( "Messages" => Array() );
foreach( $get_mails as $k => $arr ) {
  $t = Array();
  $t['CompanyName'] = $arr['company_name'];
  $t['MessageID'] = $arr['id'];
  $t['MessageBody'] = $arr['message'];

  $output['Messages'][] = $t;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

First you prepare an Array with the structure of your JSON. The syntax `$array[] = a` will append `a` to `$array`. `json_encode( ... )` at the end will take care of turning it into valid JSON, even if one of your keys included a quote or other special character that is invalid in JSON.

I believe you only want to display messages from a certain user, and try to accomplish that with `if($get_mails[0]['userid'] == $_GET['userid'])`. I recommend to change your SQL-query to something that accomplishes that, because the performance of your page will greatly increase if you try to crawl through all messages with the following code:

```
$output = Array( "Messages" => Array() );
foreach( $get_mails as $k => $arr ) {
  if( $arr['user_id'] == $_GET['userid'] ) {
    $t = Array();
    $t['CompanyName'] = $arr['company_name'];
    $t['MessageID'] = $arr['id'];
    $t['MessageBody'] = $arr['message'];

    $output['Messages'][] = $t;
  }
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

Comment: i solved my issue there was no error in my code except for the }. by the way thanks every one for their kind and nice and on time  suggestions. Thaks overstack and also all you guys.

Comment: here is my correct code if($get_mails)
{
 
 $last_key = end(array_keys($get_mails));

 echo '{"Messages":[';

 foreach($get_mails as $key => $get_each_mail){
 $company_name = $get_each_mail['company_name'];
 $email_id = $get_each_mail['id'];
 $email_body = $get_each_mail['message'];
 
 echo '{"CompanyName":"'.$company_name.'","MessageID":"'.$email_id.'","MessageBody":"'.$email_body.'"';
 
 if ($key == $last_key) 
 {
   echo '}]}';
 }else{
   echo'},';
   }
 }
 
  
 
}